# How Can I print a DataBase table through eclipse?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I already installed oracle SQLDeveloper and connect with ecplipse. (Java EE)

Then I made a table with SQLDeveloper and come back to Eclipse and write some codes to print on Chrome Server.
Here is my code on jsp file.
(the table name that I already made is "KGMember")

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%!
        
        Connection conn;        
        Statement stmt;
        
        ResultSet rs;
        
        
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; 
        
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:59161:xe";
        
        String uid = "system";
        String upw = "oracle";
        String query = "select * from KGMember";
        
    %>
    
    
    <%
        
        try{
            Class.forName("driver"); 
            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uid, upw); 
            
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
            while(rs.next()){
                
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                
                String pw = rs.getString("pw");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String phone = rs.getString("phone");
                
                out.print("id : " + id + ", password : " + pw + 
                        ", name : " + name + ", age : " + age + 
                        ", tel : " + phone + "<br>");
                
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }finally{

            try{
                
                if(rs != null)rs.close();
                if(stmt != null)stmt.close();
                if(conn != null)conn.close();
                
            }catch(Exception e2){}
            
        }
    
    %>



</body>
</html>
```

And here is my table Code on SQLDeveloper.app

```
create table KGMember(
    id varchar2(10),
    pw varchar2(10),
    name nvarchar2(10),
    age number(3),
    phone char(13)
    );
    
insert into KGMember (id, pw, name, age, phone) values('hong', '1234', '홍길동', 20, '010-1111-2222');
insert into KGMember (id, pw, name, age, phone) values('sung', '5678', '성춘향', 21, '010-1111-3333');
insert into KGMember (id, pw, name, age, phone) values('lee', '1111', '이순신', 22, '010-1111-5555');
insert into KGMember (id, pw, name, age, phone) values('jang', '2222', '장보고', 23, '010-1111-6666');

commit;

SELECT * FROM KGMember;
```

I confirm that the table is made successfully.

Then I put Ctrl F11 at Eclipse but there is nothing on the Chrome page but just being white page.
Is there any problem that I gotta fix?

Comment: What location does appear for the chrome page? you must deploy jsp files to a servlet container with jsp support to (pre)view the pages, you cannot preview them directly.

Comment: @criztovyl I have no idea what you talking about Can you explain some more please?

Comment: You've put a breakpoint in the scriptlet and debugged it? Are you sure that's the right query to get your results?

Comment: @nitind I think so because I already get the result in Window operation. And I just copied the same code and paste it on Eclipse in Mac Os. But it doesn't work..

Comment: There's a lot of detail that's missing from that last comment, like why macOS is relevant, if that same code is also in a JSP or running on a server, and what "it doesn't work" actually means. Again, have you debugged your JSP?

Comment: The page is white because you didn't query the database and output the data from the table.

Comment: *Class.forName("driver");* is not going to do it for you. `Class.forName(driver); ` is what you mean

Comment: @nitind No I haven't. I haven't tried debugging before. So I have to try it now.

Comment: @ChengThao OK I see. Then is there any problem above ? May I gotta try debugging..

Comment: fyi with JDBC version 4 on, you don't need `Class.forName`

Comment: We might make that the answer - please report back

Comment: @g00se I fixed it. And i am still trying to debug it.